# Windows 10 Lock Screen Wallpaper, where is this location?

Tags: identify-this, factoids

This image popped on my screen one day and it wouldn't give me the destination and was wondering where this is, I would love to go here.

[image: WHERE IS THIS?]

Comment: If you encounter this wallpaper again, you can click on the top-right corner ('like what you see?') It should give you an information box which gives the place where the picture is taken.

Comment: @TobyMak while this feature is great to have, it's not always available (and I find it's usually when I really want to know that it isn't there!)

Comment: It appears to be somewhere in **Indonesia** according to this [link](http://spotlight.shijuewuyu.com/RE3tI7h.html)

Comment: Also you can chose to see more pictures like this (see comment Toby Mak above).

Comment: Unless the image is grossly distorted, it might be worth a question over at physics.SE why the two rainbows appear to not be concentric

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, it is

**Wajag Island, Raja Ampat Islands, Indonesia**

Steps to find this bit of information:

1. Read [Ray's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147762/13104) and/or [3kstc's comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147757/windows-10-lock-screen-wallpaper-where-is-this-location#comment365742_147757) to find out this picture appears to have been taken somewhere in Indonesia, and taken or published by someone named Giordano Cipriani.
2. Image-google for *giordano cipriani indonesia double rainbow*.
3. For me, the first result currently is a taller version of the photo (portrait rather than landscape) that indirectly leads to a [gettyimages page of the photo](https://www.gettyimages.de/detail/foto/raja-ampat-islands-wayag-stock-fotografie/690715758), where the above location is stated.

Looking at Google Maps, the location seems at least plausible (it appears the entirety of Wajag/Waiag/Wayag (?) Island is a [maze of smaller lush islands and rocks in the sea](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Waiag/@0.1603922,130.0271453,6734m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x32a01e83e4dc727d:0x346a04d67ac368c9!8m2!3d0.1592615!4d130.0504932)). *Possibly*, what's shown in the photo is a view from coordinates 0.176352, 130.005673 (as measured on Google Maps) roughly towards WNW, but I find it hard to estimate the actual relative distances in the photo, and there are plenty of such small rocks and hills scattered around the main landmasses of Wajag.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using the Chrome browser, right click on the image and it will offer "*Search Google for image*".

If you do that with this photo, it will find:

- a bunch of rainbow images.
- your question!
- © Giordano Cipriani / SOPA / eStock Photo - Windows ...

That third one is the photo you are interested in.

Unfortunately all it says is "Indonesia", and there is no exif data with the image, but at least it gives you a place to start further research.

P.S. If you ever go there, don't count on the double rainbow having waited for you.

Comment: "it gives you a place to start further research" - [I did](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147780/13104), and your hint proved valuable. Duly upvoted.

Comment: Downvoted because Indonesia is not precise enough to actually find this location.

Comment: I tried Google’s reverse image search at work for the same wish as OP and Google informed me that it was a “Windows Seven screensaver.”